# Any way to make the mirrored mesh more idiomatic?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, add-on, edit-mode, mirror

If you turn on the edit cage for the mirrored side, then if you try to move the mirrored side vertices, they actually behave as if you were trying to move the non-mirrored side, i.e. (assuming you're mirroring the x-axis) you have to move the mouse left if you want to move the vertex right and right if you want to move it left.

VERY confusing and super annoying. Is there an  addon or something that changes this behaviour so that you can move the mirrored vertices as if they were actual vertices?

Comment: Disagree with the premise of this question. Modifiers like mirror generate geometry from the original (_"actual vertices"_)  without altering your original mesh (_"actual vertices"_)  You do not comb your reflections hair.  IMO changing behaviour to suggested would become very confusing eg vertices lying on the reflection plane.  If you want mirrored vertices to be actual vertices, apply the modifier.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't really see what would get so confusing about this. Check whether the actual or the mirrored vertex is clicked -- this check needs to happen anyway -- and if you click on the mirrored one, mirror the user drags. What's the point in making the mirrored vertices selectable and movable with the edit cage if it's going to be confusing as hell to  use?

Comment: As already answered the vert cage displayed verts are selectable, not movable. The original vert is clearly shown as selected after selecting mirror vert. You are moving the original.  It may appear trivial for the simplest of cases, imagine your mirror modifier being 10th in line of other geometry generating modifiers.  Adjusting the original vert by moving the arrayed arrayed arrayed mirrored mirrored screwed solidified and mirrored again vert by adjusting using the cage display vert  of the last modifier. Not so simple.  Modifiers modify the geometry of the original.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way to do this. You only select the vertices that you see on the geometry generated with the Mirror modifier, but what you transform are the original vertices.

You could temporarily mirror the whole object by multiplying its scale by -1 on the mirroring axis so the original geometry is on your preferred side. You can just enter -1 after pressing <kbd>s</kbd> followed by the axis, in this case <kbd>x</kbd> in object mode, or you could also use the dedicated Mirror operator(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) to do this, or just enter *-1 in the numeric input field in the n panel, Transform tab, under Scale or in the Properties Editor's Object tab.